# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Интересует вот это предложение: "Чисто выбрит, неплохо одет — он ждал меня у входа в ресторан". А конкретно интересует тире.
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы переделала: Чисто выбритый, неплохо одетый, он ждал меня у входа в ресторан. (Обособленные определения относятся к личному местоимению, поэтому обособляются).

Comment: Переделать нельзя - это письмо в газету. Могу исправить только знаки препинания.

Comment: Напишите "орфография и знаки автора" - и не заморачивайтесь. В принципе такая пунктуация возможна постольку, поскольку вся фраза - передача разговорного стиля.

Answer (score 1):

По правилам запятая, вот у Лопатина:§ 52. Всегда выделяются запятыми определения, выраженные краткими прилагательными или страдательными причастиями. Они могут занимать любое положение по отношению к определяемому слову: В привычный час пробуждена, вставала при свечах она (П.); Овеян вещею дремотой, полураздетый лес грустит (Тютч.);- Именно запятой.

Но в данном случае, думаю, возможно оставить авторское тире - как интонационное. оно как бы делит предложение на 2 части и привлекает внимание к первой.

Comment: Краткие причастия выполняют роль сказуемого. Примеры употребления их в качестве определений - все из века 19.

Comment: Ларf, а ведь верно. 
Собственно, ведь и краткие прилагательное - тоже. Нет? 
  
Но тогда - вопрос. Ведь если заменить краткие формы причастий на полные - ничего ж не изменится, запятую ведь не потребуется убирать? 

В привычный час пробужденая(,) вставала при свечах она.

Если запятая сохраняется (а иное и предположить трудно) то получается, что правило общее, даже краткость причастий осбо оговаривать не надо. Значит, против запятой не попрешь и в исходном примере. Нет?

Comment: Конечно, запятая останется. Просто причастный оборот с краткой формой причастия - устаревший вариант, поэтому я и поправила на полное причастие.